# While run the React application getting error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm-install, npm-start, react-devtools

You need to install 'webpack-dev-server' for running 'webpack serve'.
Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

I getting error like this when give npm install to run React application. Please give solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I used JHipster, which I solved by running this command

```
npm install --save-dev ajv@^7
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14492#issuecomment-810548947)